# Nattable row selection provider

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I am new to Nattable, my requirement is to highlight a selected object of nattable view to different view.
Consider 'View1' as nattable data view, it has following code:

```
getViewSite().setSelectionProvider(
                    m_gridTable.getRowSelectionProvider() );
```

and 'View2' implements ISelectionListener, but 'selectionChanged' of View2 is not getting called when I select any object in 'View1'.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: How should one answer that question without the necessary information? How do you create and set the RowSelectionProvider? How is view2 connected to the selection mechanism? To many missing information!

Comment: My apologies Dirk, I have created RowSelectionProvider using following code:
` new RowSelectionProvider<T>( selectionLayer, bodyDataProvider, true );`
selectionLayer and bodyDataProvider are created using bodyLayer of net.sourceforge.nattable.layer.ILayer type.
This is a base framework, which already exists so missed to share earlier.

Comment: View1 and View2 shared same view network. View1 is primary view and View2 is secondary one.

Comment: First, the SourceForge version is outdated for several years. We moved to Eclipse a few years ago. So I can't help in detail, since there where numerous bugfixes over the years. Second, you say that your second view implements ISelectionListener, but where do you register it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dirk! Yes, SourceForge is outdated and we have been also moving to Eclipse now, it is under process.

Comment: Regarding my actual issue, I did stupid mistake by creating RowSelectionProvider for fullySelectedRowsOnly and expecting selection change events clicking on cells etc, my bad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RowSelectionProvider was created using fullySelectedRowsOnly as true value so selection event was not fired unless user selects complete row, changing flag to false worked fine for me.